# PHP file names appending in URL during header() call

Tags: php

I have a button on **profile_page.php** called `Send Message`:

```
<form method='post'>
   <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' name='sendmsg' value='Send Message'/>
</form>
```

And I have the following, simple piece of code which on click the `Send Message` button, should take them to `messages.php/$user` - `$user` being their username:

```
if (isset($_POST['sendmsg'])){
    header("Location: messages.php?u=$user");
    }
```

Now, when I click `Send Message` the URL reads

```
http://localhost/profile_page/messages.php?u=freddy
```

Why is messages.php appending to profile_page.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what header() function does. If you want to redirect the user to a more specific route, you should use / in the beginning of the location to specify more. For example `header("Location: /messages.php?u=$user");` will lead to `http://localhost/messages.php?u=freddy`

Comment: actually you should provide the full URI in accordance with the specs

Comment: Thank you. A very educating answer.